# Apache test screen not loading. Connection refused when connecting to public ip

Tags: apache-http-server, iptables, amazon-ec2

I'm having problems getting Apache to work. I've followed the Amazon AWS instructions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) but my computer is refusing to load the Amazon Linux test screen.

While running `curl localhost`, I do see the HTML of the test screen so it probably means something is not right with the ports?

I ran `netstat -lnp` and have pasted the output below:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55001               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::49475                    :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58316               0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:974                 0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1001              0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 172.31.25.11:123            0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 :::974                      :::*                                    -                   
udp        0      0 :::53736                    :::*                                    -                   
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7784   -                   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8016   -                   @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9141   -                   /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9314   -                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

I've also followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo and accepted all traffic to port 80.

Running `sudo iptables -L -V`, I get:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
   61  4144 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    6   866 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 16 packets, 2356 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've fixed your `code formatting`. Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open 80 port for your AWS Security Group if you have not opened yet:

- Go to the Security Group settings in the left hand navigation
- Find the Security Group that your instance is apart of
- Click on Inbound Rules
- Use the drop down and add HTTP (port 80)
- Click Apply and enjoy